# How to send firebase notification to multiple topics

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have done like below for single topic to send notification which is working great:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirebaseAPI"]);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                      .Accept
                      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                       .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", "=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["projectKey"]);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "relativeAddress");
//How to Send more Id's loop it with the array

var data = new
{
    to = string.Concat("/topics/", 121),
    notification = new
    {
        body = "test",
        title = "FIRE alert"
    }
};

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

var resultArray = client.PostAsync("send", request.Content);
return resultArray.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send FCM Push Notifications to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413037/how-to-send-fcm-push-notifications-to-multiple-topics)

Comment: not exactly the duplicate questions states about conditions , my questions is how to execute send call into for loop in efficiently

Comment: Hi Neo. The post is a bit confusing. Do you mean you prefer to send to multiple topics by sending a different request for each instead of just using the `condition` parameter in your payload?

Comment: yes because at a time it is only taking 3 conditions so so example I want to send alert to 100 topics then I can not able to write condition .
so I can make a loop and want to send alert to 100 topics. make sense ?

Comment: I see. Yup. You're going to have to loop on the multiple topics, although I think that would be heavy. Depending on your use-case, it would be better to just have the clients subscribe to another topic (like a global one?), and send the message to that one. It would be easier. But you'll have to first determine which topics should be subscribed at first..

Comment: ok got you thanks :)